# Angular $watch | returning the item from function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm interested to find out why i always have to do this

```
$scope.$watch( function() {
   return $scope.someData;
}, function( value ) {
   console.log( value );
});
```

for angular to actually watch the data, why do I have to do this, this is one of the things that really bug me because it looks pointless.

If I do something like this

```
$scope.$watch($scope.someData, function( value ) {
   console.log( value );
});
```

Which is nicer, it never works?

I also use this a lot with factories

say that `$data` is a factory I have to do

```
$scope.$watch( function() {
   return $data.someData;
}, function( value ) {
   console.log( value );
});
```

Comment: do: `$scope.$watch('someData', function (...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works:

```
$scope.$watch("someData", function( value ) {
   console.log( value );
});
```

Comment: Cool, what about with a factory?

Comment: I guess you can assign the factory return to a model and watch that model.

Answer (score 23):

I guess it's worth mentioning that passing a function to `$watch` is useful when you want to monitor a condition:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { 
    return $scope.data.length > 0; 
}, function() {
    // Do something every time $scope.data.length > 0 changes
});
```

or

```
$scope.$watch(function() { 
    return $scope.prop1 && $scope.prop2;
}, function() {
    // Do something every time $scope.prop1 && $scope.prop2 changes
});
```

Comment: I've just reworded the comments in the code. The callback function is called every time the condition changes, not every time it becomes true.

Comment: In the second example. it will fire whenever each of them change right. not both of them?

Comment: It'll fire whenever `$scope.prop1 && $scope.prop2` changes. If one side changes but the condition as a whole doesn't, it won't. For instance, if both `$scope.prop1` and `$scope.prop2` are false and one of them becomes true, the expression remains false and the watch callback won't get called.

Comment: @MichaelBenford Hey Michael! This is a part of an angualr app I don't get:
    `$scope.$watch(function () {
        return $scope.model &&
               $scope.model.Test &&
               $scope.model.Test.AnotherTest;
    }, function(value) {
        if (value) {
            doSomething();
        }
    });`

based on your explanation all of those conditions should be reduced to `$scope.model.Test.AnotherTest;` am I right?

Answer (score 3):

With a factory, you need to watch a function because if you pass a string, Angular will evaluate it as an expression against the $scope.  Since $data.someData is not defined on your $scope, it won't work.

To elaborate on @Codezilla's comment, you could assign your factory data to some $scope property, and then watch that:

```
$scope.data = $data.someData;
$scope.$watch('data', function(newValue) { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the how-to-do answer is already given, I'll try to explain you what goes on actually and why it didn't work the way you tried at first time.

First of all this code sure works,

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
   return $scope.someData;
}, function(value) {
   console.log(value);
});
```

But this is **NOT** the perfect way. To be more precise `$watch` injects the `scope` in the function, like this,

```
$scope.$watch(function(injectedScope) {
   return injectedScope.someData;
}, function(value) {
   console.log(value);
});
```

Previously it works because `$scope` and `injectScope` are one and the same thing.

Now as this [article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2658-using-scope-watch-to-watch-functions-in-angularjs.htm) explains,

> Since `$scope` is passed into the watch function, it means that we can
>   watch any function that expects the scope as an argument and returns a
>   value in response. A great example of this is [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate)
>   function.

So in your case, we can also make use of `$interpolate` as following:

```
$scope.$watch($interpolate("{{someData}}"), function(value) {
    ...
});
```

Now this is where we come to the short-hand method of using just a watch expression.
`$watch` can also accept an expression, which actually is **interpolated**.

Thus by providing `$scope.$watch("someData", ... )`,

`someData` will be:

1. interpolated as `{{someData}}`
2. using the scope injected by `$watch` function

This is a nice, clean, readable, short-hand way of writing the expression instead of the actual function. But finally after all such compilations, it is ultimately the function which returns a value to watch.