# how to submit form data without using ngClick and ngSubmit

Tags: angularjs

Is there any method or tag/directive in angular js to send the data without using  ngClick and ngSubmit.

because in the both methods we have to explicitly mention function name. I want to avoid this due to security purpose?

This my code:

```
 <form name="userForm"  novalidate>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <h2 class="title-text">Get Quote</h2>

                        <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>

                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }">
                            <label>Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.name" required>
                            <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">name is required.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine }">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.email">
                            <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.subject.$invalid && !userForm.subject.$pristine }">
                            <label>subject:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.subject" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="15">
                            <p ng-show="userForm.subject.$error.minlength" class="help-block">subject is too short.</p>
                            <p ng-show="userForm.subject.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">subject is too long.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.description.$invalid && !userForm.description.$pristine }">
                            <label>Description:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.description" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="200">
                            <p ng-show="userForm.description.$error.minlength" class="help-block">description is too short.</p>
                            <p ng-show="userForm.description.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">description is too long.</p>
                        </div>

                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="btn-get-requirement" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Get Quote</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                </form>
```

can i use id attribute to submit  form data in angularjs?? Or is there any method??

Answer (score 0):

you can use $watch function for getting the value without submitting the form in controller

example : [Angular $watch | returning the item from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214774/angular-watch-returning-the-item-from-function)