# change an array length from an input box of type number

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays

I have an array that contains objects. I would like to change the number of objects in this array from an input box of type number. So each time the number in the input box is increased i increase the length and same for decrease. I will also like to push a default object or pop the last object depending on it the array in increased or decreased. Here is my current code.

```
// html
<input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" max="12" ng-click ="topEntriesSelectOffense()" ng-value="page.offense.topRow.length">

//my controller
$scope.topEntriesSelectOffense = function () {
    // push if number is increased
    $scope.page.offense.topRow.push({
        "1": {
            "firstName": "FirstName",
            "lastName": "LastName",
            "headshot": "file/path"
        },
        "2": {
            "firstName": "FirstName",
            "lastName": "LastName",
            "headshot": "file/path"
        },
        "3": {
            "firstName": "FirstName",
            "lastName": "LastName",
            "headshot": "file/path"
        },
        "position": "POS"
    });
    // pop if the number is reduced
    $scope.page.offense.topRow.pop();
}
```

The problem is i cant really tell when a user reduces the number and i am not quite sure how to detect the value increase or reduction. If i use ng-model for the page.offense.topRow.length i will get an array that has no object at an index after the last because it will increase the lenght then push the object leaving a gap in the array. the array would look like this array = [1, 3]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have 2 functions, `createObj()` to create the object and `destroyObj()` to destroy the object in the array.

Now you say that you need to add/subtract objects as per the variable in the input.

In this case I would insist on reading `$watch` function of angularjs.
What you could do here is that you could have 2 variables, namely oldvar and newVar and the compare and call the required function as many times as required. Eg- if the initial val was 10 and user makes it 7, then you can call the `destroy()` function 3 times.

Here is angular [doc link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) for the `$watch` function

Here's another helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214774/angular-watch-returning-the-item-from-function) from stackoverfllow to give a simple example of how to use it.

Comment: I like the idea of using a $watch function i have been trying to get the watch function to work, but it does not seem to be fired each time the input box is changed here is my code, `$scope.$watch('topEntriesOffense', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if ( newValue > oldValue ) {
                topEntriesOffenseAdd();
            }
        }
    );`

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I used an ng-change as Soviut suggested and just when it changes i call a function to creatObj()  and destroyObj() like you suggested depending on the current value of the model. I saved the old value in a scope variable and the current value would be retrieved in the function by calling this.value. I could not get the watch to work properly.  But this way works pretty well. Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: Glad to be help. however i am curious to as to why the `$watch` function did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-change` instead of `ng-click` on your number field. This will make sure it fires the event even when keyboard input or copy/paste is used.

Then, inside your change handler function, simply ask for the current value and use the array `splice()` function to grow or shrink the array.